# How to click button under an element that have click event as well

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table in html. And I am having click event on each row of that table. I have 4 items on each row and the last item in dropdown. I want to prevent row click when I click on drop down item and vice versa.

```
<tr onclick="doSomething()">
  <td>text</td>
  <td>text</td>
  <td>text</td>
  <td onclick="doSomethingElse()">
    <!-- drop down elements -->
  </td>
</tr>
```

I know something about preventDefault(); but don't know how to use  that here.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with z-index?

Comment: That is `event.stopPropagation();`?

Comment: Ya, but it didn't work. gave z-index value greater for td onclick()

Comment: z-index wont work. Its an event. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

preventDefault is not needed here. You can easily achieve it using `stopPropogation()`

```
 <tr onclick="doSomething()">
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td onclick="doSomethingElse(); event.stopPropagation(); ">
         <!-- drop down elements -->
    </td>
</tr>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the event as one of the arguments in the doSomething function, then check whether the event target is the father element. See this example

```
function doSomething(e) {
    if(e.target == document.getElementById('father')) {
        //do stuff
    }
};
```

Then in the HTML you just need to add the event argument to the javascript function.

```
<tr id="father" onclick="doSomething(event)">
  <td>text</td>
  <td>text</td>
  <td>text</td>
  <td id="son" onclick="doSomethingElse(event)">
    <!-- drop down elements -->
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for e.target or Event Target function

```
function somefunction(e) {
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  target.style.display= 'block';
}
```

Another stuff you might need

```
var target = event.target;
var parent = target.parentElement;//parent of "target"
```

Comment: No, this is wrong way to solve this. You should not get into `somefunction` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `document.querySelector` rather than `onclick`, you can do this instead, for example:

```
let variable_name = querySelector...();

variable_name.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
     let clicked_event = event.target.innerHTML;

     if (clicked_event !="text") {
         doSomething()
     }
});
```